# how many zookeeper node is suitable?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I know that with more node number ,zookeeper will be more fault tolerate and faster with read but the write performance will be worse.

I wander is there any best node number for a zookeeper cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 is suitable for most use-cases, but 5 or 7 would be most fault tolerant

There's no reason to have more than that